# Bijection between monoid of nilpotent decreasing self-maps and local subsemigroup

Tags: co.combinatorics, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $\mathcal{C}_X\cong\mathcal{C}_n$ be the monoid of self-maps $\alpha$ of $X=\{1\dots,n\}$ that are order-preserving ($\forall x,y$, $x\le y$ $\Rightarrow$ $\alpha(x)\le\alpha(y)$) and decreasing ($\forall x$, $\alpha(x)\le x$).

Let N($\mathcal{C_n})$ be all nilpotent elements of $\mathcal{C}_n$, i.e., those $\alpha\in\mathcal{C}_n$ such that some power of $\alpha$ equals the absorbing element (the constant function $1$); if $\alpha^r=1$ for smallest $r$ say that $\alpha$ is $r$-nilpotent.

Let $a\in\mathcal{C}_n$ be any $r$-nilpotent and $a\mathcal{C}_na$ is a local subsemigroup of $\mathcal{C}_n$. Then I guess that there is a well-defined bijection 
$a\mathcal{C}_na\to N(\mathcal{C}_r)$.
Although I have tried many times, I could not construct it.

Comment: You don't define $r$-nilpotent, do you mean $a^r=1$? Also "there is a well-defined bijection between $X$ and $Y$" means that $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinal. Is this what you want? Or you want a semigroup isomorphism?

Comment: $a$ is an $r$-nilpotent means that $a^r=0$. $0$ is the constant map to $1$ for self monoid. I know it is not an isomorphism. Actullay, I investigate a lot examples if $a$ is an $r$-nilpotent  then $a\mathcal{C_n}a$ and $N(\mathcal{C}_r)$ have the same cardinality. I think bijection should exist. But, I could not construct it.

Comment: Has your element $a$ always rank $r$?  If it does then $aC_na$ can be identified as a subsemigroup of $N(C_r)$ by restricting the action to the range of a.  Maybe you get all of $N(C_r)$ that way.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg If $a$ is an $r$-nilpotent then  rank ($a$) can be grater than $r$. I dont think your advised case.

Comment: I didn't think they all had rank r.

Comment: I find a counter-example. Let $a=\left( \begin{array}{cccccc} 1  & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6  \\ 1  & 1  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 5\end{array}\right)$. hen the cardinality of $aC_na$ is $3$, but  the cardinality of $N(C_3)$ is $2$.

Comment: Is it possible the calculate the cardinality of $aC_na$ for  $r$-nilpotent $a$?